# Surface View and Linear layout and onClick event

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a problem with adding my surface view to a linear layout, I have tried the already available answers and still cant seem to figure it out. My aim is to render an animation at the bottom of my login screen when my the next button is clicked. I tried adding a linear Layout to the Screen and then adding my gameView object on to that.

This is the loginActivity and game View Class for clarity I've also added the xml.

```
    `package com.example.Combat;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        /**
         * Called when the activity is first created.
         */

        public GameView gameView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //setting the font

            Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Typo Oxin free promo.ttf");
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeFace);



            gameView = new GameView(this);

    //        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //        lp.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;


           LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            myLayout.findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutView);
           myLayout.addView(gameView);


        }

        @Override

        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            gameView.resume();
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            gameView.pause();
        }




        public void beginMotion(View view) {

            GameView.isMoving=!GameView.isMoving;

           // startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),transitionActivity.class));
        }





    }
    `


        package com.example.Combat;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.*;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

    /**
     * Created by vmuser on 2017/05/05.
     */
    public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

        private Thread gameThread;
        private SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        public static volatile boolean playing=false;
        private Canvas canvas;
        private Bitmap bitmapRunningMan;
        public  static boolean isMoving=false;
        private float runSpeedPerSecond = 150;

        //LinearLayout screen=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theScreen);



        private float manXPos = 1020, manYPos = 950;
        private int frameWidth = 230, frameHeight = 274;
        private int frameCount = 6;
        private int currentFrame = 0;
        private long fps;
        private long timeThisFrame;
        private long lastFrameChangeTime = 0;
        private int frameLengthInMillisecond = 60;

        private Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        private RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(manXPos, manYPos, manXPos + frameWidth, frameHeight);

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ourHolder = getHolder();
            bitmapRunningMan = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.perfectsoldier);
            bitmapRunningMan = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapRunningMan,
                    frameWidth * frameCount, frameHeight, false);



        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (playing) {
                long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                update();
                this.draw();

                Log.d("theOne","its Happennig");

                timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;

                if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
                    fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
                }
            }
        }

        public void update() {
            if (isMoving) {
                manXPos = manXPos - runSpeedPerSecond / fps;



                if (manXPos > 0) {
                    //manYPos += (int) frameHeight;
                    //manXPos = 10;

                    isMoving=false;
                }

                if (manYPos + frameHeight > 0) {
                    // manYPos = 10;
                    isMoving=false;
                }
            }
        }


        public void manageCurrentFrame() {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (isMoving) {
                if (time > lastFrameChangeTime + frameLengthInMillisecond) {
                    lastFrameChangeTime = time;
                    currentFrame++;

                    if (currentFrame >= frameCount) {
                        currentFrame = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            frameToDraw.left = currentFrame * frameWidth;
            frameToDraw.right = frameToDraw.left + frameWidth;
        }

        public void draw() {
            if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                whereToDraw.set((int) manXPos, (int) manYPos, (int) manXPos
                        + frameWidth, (int) manYPos + frameHeight);
                manageCurrentFrame();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapRunningMan, frameToDraw, whereToDraw, null);
                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }


        public void pause() {
            playing = false;

            try {
                gameThread.join();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERR", "Joining Thread");
            }
        }

        public void resume() {
            playing = true;
            gameThread = new Thread(this);
            gameThread.start();
        }

    //    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //        switch (event.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    //            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
    //                isMoving = !isMoving;
    //                break;
    //        }
    //
    //        return true;
    //    }




    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              android:color="#000000"
              android:weightSum="1" android:background="#ffffff" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/theScreen">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thelogo"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="combat"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:id="@+id/nameTextView" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight="0.06"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:textColor="#22272a"
            android:id="@+id/userNameEditText" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="261dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/thearrow"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:onClick="beginMotion"
            android:id="@+id/NextButton" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="#638455"
    />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Create an account"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.07"
            android:textColor="#22272A"/>

<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/gameLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't attached myLayout to the activity main layout that you earlier set on setContentView(R.layout.main).

Instead of:

```
 LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 myLayout.findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutView);
 myLayout.addView(gameView);
```

You should write this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutView);
myLayout.addView(gameView);
```

Comment: Im alittle confused, isnt that what,                                                             LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    myLayout.findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutView);
  myLayout.addView(gameView); is supposed to do, this might be stupid but, how would attach the layout ?

Comment: myLayout.addView(gameView); - add the game view to the linear view
myLayout.findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutView); - returns the view inside myLayout with the specified id.
Could you please add the XML files to the question so I could give a better answer